# this.date is undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have created an object in JavaScript to show the today day and date.

But it's reflecting error of this.date is undefined. Please help.

```
var getTodayDate = {
    getMonthName : function(month){
        var months = ["January", "Fabruary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        return months[month];
    },

    abbrName : function(text){
        return text.substr(0, 3);
    },

    date : function(){
        return new Date();
    },

    myMessage : function(t){
        var arr = [
            "Hello, ",
            prompt("Enter your full name", "") || "Stranger",
            " today is ",
            this.abbrName(this.getMonthName(this.date.getMonth())),
            " ",
            this.date.getDate(),
            ", ",
            this.date.getFullYear(),
            "."
        ];

        return arr.join("");
    }
}

alert(getTodayDate.myMessage());
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xfb3b/2/)

Comment: -1 for having different code here and in fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is a function which returns a `Date` object. You should call it once, and use the created `Date` object to call `getMonth()`, `getDate()` and `getFullYear()`:

```js
var date = this.date();
var arr = [
    "Hello, ",
    prompt("Enter your full name", "") || "Stranger",
    " today is ",
    this.abbrName(this.getMonthName(date.getMonth())),
    " ",
    date.getDate(),
    ", ",
    date.getFullYear(),
    "."
];
```

Answer (score 0):

change all your

```
this.date.X
```

to

```
this.date().X
```

so your code looks like:

```
myMessage : function(t){
    var arr = [
        "Hello, ",
        prompt("Enter your full name", "") || "Stranger",
        " today is ",
        this.abbrName(this.getMonthName(this.date().getMonth())),
        " ",
        this.date().getDate(),
        ", ",
        this.date().getFullYear(),
        "."
    ];

    return arr.join("");
}
```